# Is the inconsistent (or paraconsistent) line a possibility?

Tags: philosophy-of-mathematics, ontology

According to the [SEP](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/mathematics-inconsistent/):

> Another place to find applications of inconsistency in analysis is topology, where one readily observes the practice of cutting and pasting spaces being described as “identification” of one boundary with another.

For example, joining the segments [-1,0] & [0,1] at 0.

> One can show that this can be described in an inconsistent theory in which the two boundaries are both identical and not identical, and it can be further argued that this is the most natural description of the practice.

Now points do not have boundaries, so we can't construct a line by 'joining' points, as one might imagine (the usual construction is to give (not join) a bare set of points and then add the right topology); but can we consider a limiting argument? That is:

Consider, in one picture, that the real line is made of line segments, say of unit size; and joined end-to-end; as in the example above; using inconsistent joins.

Then take the limit as the interval size goes to zero.

Does this work as a definition of the inconsistent real line?

Comment: I don't know if this would qualify as an answer because I don't know if I'm understanding correctly. The points of the joined set consist of [-1,0) and (0,1] together with the equivalence class {0,0} where these are considered to be two different 0's coming from two different spaces. So {0,0} is a point. This is not the same as [-1,1], but it is homeomorphic with the quotient topology. There isn't really any joining going on, we are constructing a new space. I don't understand how this is inconsistent.

Comment: @Samuel: This is right, but not what they are arguing for; the usual picture, the one you explicated, is one where no actual join is done - its a mirage; the 'natural' one is to simply consider the two end-points as 'merged' or 'joined'; and presumably this is what they means here; to do this in a classical logic, (I'm assuming here) can't be pushed through ie it becomes inconsistent; but according to the SEP, it is possible in some non-classical paraconsistent logic; I don't know the details of the theory; so would be interested in an account of it.

Comment: First you take the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint_union_(topology) then you put an equivalence relation on the points and construct the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_space_(topology) .

Comment: @MattSamuel: I do know those details :), I meant the inconsistent variety!

Comment: I see. Hence your question. Got it.

Comment: "*Does this work as a definition of the inconsistent real line?*" Define 'work': apart from inconsistency, what properties do you want from the inconsistent real line? I think this line of yours may distinguish (and not-distinguish) 0.9999... from 1; and 0.1111... from 1/9; and 1/3+1/9+1/27+... from 1/2; etc. It might admit "the ghosts of departed quantities", but only by using limits to define them. It is not at all clear that any equalities will hold that are not also inequalities. What do such things buy you?

Comment: @MoziburUllah Can you please say more about what you mean by inconsistent line? The SEP article doesn't go into detail. There's no inconsistency gluing [-1,0] to [0,1]. It's more usual to do things like taking the unit interval [0,1] and gluing (identifying) 0 with 1 to make a circle. But there's no inconsistency there either. Can you provide some references as to what you might mean by an inconsistent identification? In any event I don't think your limit example holds water but that's a separate issue.

Comment: @de beaudrap: a different perspective on Zenos paradoxes of motion, possibly;

Comment: @user4894: I just did in the question - check the SEP entry and its bibliography; I'm not saying that it must be possible, just whether it is possible. If it is possible it won't be inconsistent in a sense; as the notion will have to be built up via a theory that remains consistent.

Comment: After all, in its precise mathematical formulation - and I'm guessing to a large extent here given my slight acquaintance of Model Theory, the Meta-language will remain consistent, but the arbitrary axiomatic system, its inner language will have an interpretation for some of its axioms as inconsistency of some form; but I think there is also a symbolic form.

Comment: @de beaudrap: after all, one can't deny now surely, that the intuitionistic line exists (aka Kocks Synthetic Geometry), though I haven't seen it applied to the paradoxes of Zeno.